# Database design for optional fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I've got 3 tables:

1. orders
2. line_items
3. products

They're setup as:

> *order* has many *products* through *line_items*

This allows me to store in *line_items* such things as the product_id, quantity, price at time of purchase, discount, etc...

All is well up to this point.

**What I'm looking to achieve:**

I now need to have **some** products that have a user changeable **status**. Meaning that at some point in the future after an order has been processed, the **purchased** product **status** can be changed from one status to another.

The product table has a **statusable** boolean field that tracks whether said product supports a status.

**The question:**

Would I just add a status field in line_items? Only a small amount of the products will require a status so it feels like a waste but I'm not sure how else to approach this hurdle. My main concern being that I'll end up with a massive table as the application grows and specific products require extra optional fields.

Comment: Your `order` and `line_item` records should be *immutable*, in *append-only tables*, as should the copies of *product* for the orders. So if you must change something after the fact, I'd put it in separate table like `product_status` that you can insert status rows into at order creation time for products that can have a status. Make that table updateable so you can update the status and *only* the status later. It should be impossible for users to edit any other part of the order after the fact - they should have to *append* amendments instead.

Comment: Rationale: The order is a record of something that happened, not live state. So it should be immutable. Mistakes should be corrected with journaled amendments.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger for the explanation, would you mind answering this corollary. If an order has a state (i.e. shipped), should that not be a field in the orders table?

Comment: @Vasseurth Well, you could use database column-level permissions to grant `INSERT` on all `order` columns but only grant `UPDATE` on the `state` column, I guess. Personally I'd use a side-table so I could keep `orders` append-only, but that's a design preference. Either way you should make sure no other columns can be changed.

Comment: Totally agree @CraigRinger. To be clear, you're suggesting a simple table for each post-purchase configurable product option and programmatically assigning the line_item.id to the option?

Comment: @Vasseurth I'd also say to be careful with putting the shipped state on the order. Especially if you support partial shipping, in that case you'd want to manage it at the line item level.

Comment: Well, I hardly know what the actual data model and real needs are, so all I can do is make very broad comments. It *sounds* like a `product_status (order_id integer, product_id integer, primary key(order_id, product_id), status whatevertype)` table would be appropriate, but it's hard to know w/o a real analysis of the problem with full details. Also, Rails is probably going to explode and die if you do anything like actually use database features like composite keys and column permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for this:

> 1. Create a column in the join model
> 2. Create a separate "statuses" table, which you can use to create specific status updates

--

**Attribute**

I would personally create a column in the join model to support a `status`. Yes, it will require you to have that column for every `line_item`, but it will make the process much simpler, and will give extensibility without massive issues

You'll be best using one of the [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) gems ([`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), [`aasm_state`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm)) to provide:

```
#app/models/line_item.rb
Class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :active, :initial => true
    state :inactive

    event :activate do
      transitions :from => :inactive, :to => :active
    end

    event :deactivate do
      transitions :from => :active, :to => :inactive
    end
  end
end
```

This will give you the ability to directly affect the status of the `line_item` model

--

**Associated Model**

Alternatively, you may want to create a different table / model:

```
#app/models/line_item_status.rb
Class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
   #field id | line_item_id | status | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :line_item
end

#app/models/line_item.rb
Class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :status
   delegate :status, to: :status #-> allows you to call @line_item.status
end
```

This will give you the ability to set the status for each product, making your data tables more efficient by only including a single `status` for each `line_item`

Comment: Thanks @RichPeck, how would you deal with the addition of other post-purchase mutable properties? For example, some products have a state which your solution addresses but looking into the future as other products require different properties such as some products may be redeemable and so on... Feels like there'd be a better way to manage that instead of creating an associated model for each new mutable product property. Hope that makes sense.